# How do I format a numeric value in php?

Tags: php

I have to print a numeric value which is less than 10 in the following format:

```
for 0 I want to print it 00
for 1 I want to print it 01
for 2 I want to print it 02
```

Are there any php library functions which will format numbers in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`printf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) or [`sprintf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$i = 1;
printf('%02d', $i);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/wVpDH)**.

The `sprintf` page also documents the syntax for formatting specifiers (`%02d`), so you can also see what other options are available.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf('%02u', $number)
```

http://php.net/sprintf

Answer (score 2):

Use str_pad function.

`str_pad($number_str,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)`

[PHP Manual - str-pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value is less than ten and concatenate using the dot operator '.', i.e.

```
if($i < 10 && $i >0) print '0'.$i;
else print $i;
```